# How can I Add EditText every time I click on the Button?

Tags: java, android, xml

assume I have " `activity_main.xml` " it has a button called " `@+id/clickAndAdd` ". and I have another XML file called " `second.xml` " it has a EditText called " `@+id/myEditText` "

How can I add " `@+id/myEditText` " in my " `activity_main.xml` " every time I click on " `@+id/clickAndAdd` "

thank you.

Comment: Please read some basic Android tutorials first.

Comment: I read, and I know about many thing. But this subject I confuse about it. I know it about addView.

Comment: Instead of making us "_assume you have ..._" just post the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically create a view (in this case, edittext) by writing the following code in your java file.

```
//Main layout ID in your activity_main.xl
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutHorizontal);

//Creating the edittext
EditText editTextOne = new EditText(this);

//You can also add properities here
editTextOne.setHint("Hello World");
editTextOne.setHintTextColor(Color.CYAN);

//Adding the edittext to the xml file
mainLayout.addView(editTextOne);
```

Here's a good tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity it is using activity_main.xml as the layout default. So your clickAndAdd button will be display at there. But I'm not much clear your question where you want to add your EditText. If you want to call another activity you can do it using

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NexActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

For more information you can get from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html